# Chrome reloads page differently than expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple html page with two "spaces"

```html
<div class="space1">
  <div class="arrowleft"></div>
</div>

<div class="space2">
  <div class="arrowright"></div>
</div>
```

and some js code to switch in between those spaces

```js
let arrowLeft = document.querySelector(".arrowleft");
let arrowRight = document.querySelector(".arrowright");

arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.classList.add("right");
})

arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.classList.remove("right")
})
```

The css file looks like this:

```css
body{
  width: 200vw;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

body.right {
  left: -100vw;
}

.space1{
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

.space2{
  left: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

In chrome, if I am in space2 and reload the page, instead of going back to the original state, it reloads back into space2, but since the class ".right" is not applied to the body the arrow to go back to space1 doesn't work.

This problem only happens in chrome and persists even if I remove the cache. I've tried applying the class and removing it right away but it doesn't work.

Comment: weird... I tried your code with the same result, a bug in chrome ? Chrome is not adding the class to body on reload, but acts as if the class were active...